# Database query - unusual query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to transfer a query to LINQ

It's a bit complicated and I don't know if I'm doing the right thing

There is also a problem with SELECT to save it properly

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(1),0) TotalSubmitted, 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Pic.PhotoFileName IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),0) TotalAssigned 
FROM tblFromPhone Ph 
INNER JOIN tblOfficer O ON Ph.OfficerCode = O.Code 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT PhotoFileName FROM tblPhotos P 
WHERE P.validityTo IS NULL 
AND P.PhotoFileName = Ph.DocName 
AND P.OfficerID = O.OfficerID)Pic 
WHERE CAST(Ph.LandedDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate 
AND O.ValidityTo IS NULL 
AND DocType = N'E' 
AND OfficerCode = @OfficerCode
```

My LINQ:

```
var res = (from FP in context.TblFromPhone
           join O in context.TblOfficer on FP.OfficerCode equals O.Code
           join P in context.TblPhotos on FP.DocName equals P.PhotoFileName into P
           from Ph in P.Where(x => x.OfficerId == O.OfficerId).DefaultIfEmpty()
           where Ph.ValidityTo == null
           where FP.LandedDate >= DateTime.Parse(fromDate)
           && FP.LandedDate <= DateTime.Parse(toDate)
           && O.ValidityTo == null
           && FP.DocType == "E"
           && FP.OfficerCode == officerCode
           select new EnrolmentModel()
           {
               TotalSubmitted = // How to make?
               TotalAssigned = // How to make?
           })
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Do `count(Pic.PhotoFileName)` instead of that ISNULLSUMCASE...

Comment: Please show the class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?). This is necessary because the best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query. Also, it's not clear what you mean here: 'There is also a problem with SELECT to save it properly'. What is 'a problem'? And what does a select statement *save*?

Comment: Take a look at the LINQPad tool for converting between SQL and LINQ